# Ajax post executed twice and adding up

Tags: ajax, function

I'm facing an issue with ajax that several users here also encountered but the proposed solution do not seem to work for my case.

in my index.php file, I have:

```
<pre>
<script>
function ButtonManager()
    {
        $( "button" ).click(function() 
            {    
                var context = $(this).attr('type');
                var page_type = $(this).attr('page');
                var referrer = $(this).attr('referrer');
                var form_type = $(this).attr('form');
                var object_id = $(this).attr('object');                                 
                var postData = 'page_type='+page_type+'&form_type='+form_type+'&referrer='+referrer+'&id='+object_id;




                $( '#indicator' ).css( "display", "block" ); 

                if (context == 'post_form')
                    {
                        var formData = $('#submit_content').serialize();
                        postData = postData+'&context=post_form&'+formData;
                    }

                if ((context == 'load_form') || (context == 'filter_form'))
                    {
                        postData = postData +'&context=load_form';
                        if (context == 'filter_form')
                            {   
                                var filter1 = $('select[name=filter1]').val();
                                var filter2 = $('select[name=filter2]').val();
                                var filter3 = $('select[name=filter3]').val();
                                postData = postData + '&filter1='+filter1+'&filter2='+filter2+'&filter3='+filter3;
                            }
                    }   


                $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'php/sl.php',
                        data: postData,
                        cache: false, 
                        async: false,
                        dataType: 'html', 
                        success: function(result) 
                            {   
                                ManageLayer(form_type+'_content');
                                $('#'+form_type+'_content').html(result);
                                $( '#indicator' ).css( "display", "none" );                                             
                            },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                            {
                                alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                                $( '#indicator' ).css( "display", "none" ); 
                            },

                    }); 

            });



    }
</script>
<button type="load_form" page="home" referrer="navigation" form="edit" object="">test</button>
</pre>
```

when a click on the test button, the script calls sl.php to retrieve some html with other buttons in it.

in the output I get from the server I have added:

```
<pre>
<script>
var myvar=ButtonManager();
</script>
<button type="post_form" page="home" referrer="navigation" form="edit" object="">test2</button>
</pre>
```

The goal of the ButtonManager function is to manage all my buttons in one function so it needs to be available/known everywhere (in index.php where it's loaded and in all the output I can get from sl.php).

I have added the var myvar=ButtonManager() line because it's the only way I have found to make sure the function is known by the server output. The drawback is that the function is executed multiple times instead of one even if I don't click on the test2 button.

So I'm looking either for a way to prevent my function from being executed multiple times or an alternative to make the function available everywhere.

I don't know what approach would be the best, I'm a casual developper programming for fun and javascript / ajax is not the language I know the best.

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another forum but I wanted to share it in case others are having the same problem.

Code to be used should be like this:

```
<pre>
$( document ).on("click", "button", function() {

</pre>
```

It makes the function available to objects that do not exist yet.